# Editing the last bit of MAC addresses in a file to f

Tags: ip, notepad++

I am looking to edit a file containing MAC addresses to all end in f

Example

```
    <accessPointMeasurement mac="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"/>

    <accessPointMeasurement mac="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xf"/>
```

I've tried looking on the site how to do it and can select only the MAC addresses but I can't do the final part of changing the last part. There are several thousand and need a way to change them all at once.

Can anyone help?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=<accessPointMeasurement mac="[^"]{16})f`
- Replace with: `Whatever you want to replace the f`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

`(?<= ... )` is called [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), it's a zero length assertion.

Comment: Thank You so much, i tweaked it slightly to be (?<=<accessPointMeasurement mac="[^"]{16}).* and replaced it with f so all the MAC addresses now end in f. Thank You very much